# Problem with ALBERT pretrained model on TF Hub

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I've tried to test the ALBERT model on TF Hub. I got the following error when just trying to load ALBERT from TF Hub:

```
python
Python 3.6.8 (default, May 16 2019, 05:58:38)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36.0.1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow_hub as hub
>>> albert_module = hub.Module(
...     "https://tfhub.dev/google/albert_base/1",
...     trainable=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/opc/vuh/tools/pyvenv3-gpu-tf-hub/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module.py", line 170, in __init__
    tags=self._tags)
  File "/home/opc/vuh/tools/pyvenv3-gpu-tf-hub/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py", line 340, in _create_impl
    name=name)
  File "/home/opc/vuh/tools/pyvenv3-gpu-tf-hub/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py", line 382, in __init__
    op.name for op in self._meta_graph.meta_info_def.stripped_op_list.op})
  File "/home/opc/vuh/tools/pyvenv3-gpu-tf-hub/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py", line 822, in register_ops_if_needed
    % missing_ops.difference(set(cpp_registry_ops.keys())))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Graph ops missing from the python registry ({'BatchMatMulV2'}) are also absent from the c++ registry.
```

Do anyone know why? Thanks so much in advance?

FYI, in my python3 venv, I am using:

tensorflow-datasets      1.1.0
tensorflow-estimator     1.13.0
tensorflow-gpu           1.13.1
tensorflow-hub           0.6.0
tensorflow-metadata      0.14.0
tensorflow-probability   0.7.0
tf-sentencepiece         0.1.83
sentencepiece            0.1.82

Comment: It will work if using with tensorflow >= 1.14.0.

Comment: You need to use tensflow 2.0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you answered your own question, but to make this more obvious for others:

You need to use tensorflow >= 1.14.0. The necessary op (BatchMatMulV2) was not present in older versions of TF.